# Going to the apps screen when pressing the back button in android

Tags: android, start-activity, onbackpressed

I have an android app my app needs to go to the Apps screen when i press Back button, So i'am using the following code for that purpose

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
 { 
    Intent i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(i); 
}
```

But it doesn't work and say "unfortunately Your application has stopped"
who know what is the problem , or provide another way to do same thing

Comment: @Hoo what is logcat? sorry i'am beginner

Comment: look like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=logcat+in+android+studio&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=955&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAmoVChMIga_RiPGIyQIVxCOUCh0uZABN#imgrc=_h3B2Q8JFvMnPM%3A)

Comment: the Console is Empty

Comment: it will shows the error when it crashed

Comment: U want to go to the first screen of your app or to the previous screen on bck press ?

Comment: @NikPatel https://www.google.iq/search?q=apps+screen&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=653&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIt_Hb_vaIyQIVAt4sCh1T0gE9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using below Intent. This intent will start the Launcher app that the user has defined.

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Or you can also use this one line solution:

```
moveTaskToBack(true);  // activity.moveTaskToBack(true)
```

it will behave as Home Button is pressed

Comment: `moveTaskToBack(true);` solved is the thing that i wanted, Thanks alot

Comment: Why vote down!! some people are poor in English , and cant express the thing that they want . . .
StackOverflow should concern these ones...

Comment: There are many reasons why your post get downvoted. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react)

Comment: @HamreenAhmad pleasure's all mine :)

Answer (score 1):

If you  want to back to your app screen, you may try this.I hope this will help!

```
   @Override 
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  { 
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) { 
            // do something on back.
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS); 
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            startActivity(i); 

           this.finish(); 
            return true; 
        } 

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    }
```